# Override the value of accessing a class

Tags: python, class, module

Assuming the following module:

`hello.py`

```
class A(object):
  _hidden = 987
  b = 654
  c = 321
```

Now, assume when importing the `hello` module, we need the following variables to evaluate like this:

```
import hello

hello.A   # evaluates to 987
hello.A.b # evaluates to 654
hello.A.c # evaluates to 321
```

We can add anything to the `hello.py` module (but the class definition must remain as is), and we can't change the syntax of the test at all. What would you do to "override" the value of `hello.A` to return the `_hidden` attribute?

Comment: `hello.py` - `A, b, c = range(3)`?

Comment: insert `A, b, c = A._hidden, A.b, A.c` after the class definition. But a more serious question: Are you looking for an `Enum`?

Comment: This question is confusing, not because it's hard to answer as written, but because an answer like @TigerhawkT3's is so straightforward that it's hard not to suspect that it's ruled out by some unmentioned constraint.

Comment: @DSM - updated the question with some more contraints

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 check out the question again

Comment: @MSeifert, check out the question again

Comment: The class itself should be equal to 0? I'm not sure if that's even possible. Are you sure it shouldn't be `hello.A() == 0`?

Comment: @Rawing - yes, I'm sure - `hello.A` itself must equal the int

Comment: My original comment stands. Just add that code (for whatever arbitrary values you seem to want) right after the useless class definition.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That doesn't work anymore. You can't have `A = 987` _and_ `A.b = 654`.

Comment: @michaelrbock I may be mistaken but what exactly do you want to achieve here and **why**? It really looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Rawing - Oh I see; the access names changed as well. That's substantively different from the original question, but it hadn't been answered yet, so I guess it's okay.

Comment: @MSeifert, you're 100% correct this is an XY problem. That being said, I'm still interested to see if this is possible

Comment: "evaluates to" is not concretely testable.  Decide on exactly what assert you want to pass -- `str(A) == 987`, `A == 987`, whatever, and state that.

Answer (score 0):

`A` is either a custom class from which you can fetch more attributes, or it is an integer number.

If `hello.A` is the integger `987` you can't get `987.b`, ordinarilly to get another value.

Unless, of course,  `A` is itself an instance of an specialized subclass of `int` which implements the extra `b` and `c` attributes. That is feasible for demonstration purposes, but of course is a solution for nothing - you should really post what your real problem is, not the path you are looking for.

In this case, in order to have the value in the "_hidden" attribute, I'd suggest using a class decorator that possibly would allow you to have A as an special instance of a custom int subclass:

```
def converter(cls):
    class MyInt(int):
        pass

    for attr in cls.__dict__:
        if not attr.startswith('__'):
            setattr(MyInt, attr, cls.__dict__[attr])
    return MyInt(cls._hidden)


@converter
class A:
    _hidden = 987
    b = 654
    c = 321
```

In the interactive prompt:

```
In [14]: A
Out[14]: 987

In [15]: A.b
Out[15]: 654

In [16]: A.c
Out[16]: 321
```

Of course, `A` can no longer work as a "class" - it is an integger.

And if you can't change this source, and have to monkey-patch the hello.py file:

```
import hello

def converter(cls):
   ...

hello.A = converter(hello.A)
```